# How can I store database passwords and usernames on my java project?

Tags: java, mysql

Storing MySQL database usernames and passwords in the source code would make it vulnerable to decompilers. Is it possibly to securely store these without the need of a RESTAPI? (This is on a android application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database usernames and passwords and more generally credentials should be stored indeed in a safe place.
Besides, they may differ according to the runtime environment where the application is deployed on.
Coupling this information to the build is both not safe and not flexible.
A good practice is storing them as properties on the running environment where only authorized users (system admin) may read it.

Comment: If I store it in properties, would de-comilers be able to get them (since technically there not compiled in binary, from source code). Keep in mind I'm talking about a android application.

Comment: "Keep in mind I'm talking about a android application" You  have not specified it.  Anyway, why do you want to provide in the Android app the credentials ?  This has to be stored on the back end server.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that (RESTAPI), but how would it know if the "give user x" query request came from the app, or a someone not authorized?

Comment: @wowzers25wow why would you care if the request comes from your frontend or another frontend? As long as the user is able to authenticate, you should provide the data requested (granted that the user is authorized to access the requested data).

Comment: Oh I think I see how it should work: IAP purchased -> App sends receipt to RESTAPI -> RESTAPI verifies with googles servers -> if successful RESTAPI gives virtual goods and a success boolean is returned. RIght?